# Is there any possibility to convert all columns in rows of pandas/numpy to arrays of bytes?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I need to convert each row of pandas/numpy array to 1, new column. I need the fastest method. I tried to find a method to extract full row as byte array, but cannot find any option, without iterating all columns, converting each column value to byte and concatenate.

In function row_to_bytes I use hashlib library and md5 function, but I don't need cryptography. Should I implement it in C/C++ or maybe there is some library which I can use?

Now, it's the best method I have, but it is very slow (I have table with 5mln records and 40 attributes).

```
hashed = df.apply(lambda row: self.row_to_bytes(row), axis=1)
```

Thanks for each suggestion.

---

I created test code:

```
import pandas as pd  
import numpy as np  
df = pd.DataFrame([["1",1],["2",2]])  
x = df.values  

def compute(x):  
    dtype = np.dtype('S{:d}'.format(x.shape[1] * x.dtype.itemsize))  
    y = np.frombuffer(x.tobytes(), dtype=dtype)  
    print(y)  
compute(x)
```

When I run code in command line several times I receive different results:

```
python test.py
[b'\xb0\x8a\xbb\x8c\xf3\x01\x00\x000\x80og'
 b'p%\xc1\x8c\xf3\x01\x00\x00P\x80og'] 

python test.py     
[b'\xb0\x8aCr,\x02\x00\x000\x80og' b'p%^r,\x02\x00\x00P\x80og'] 

python test.py
[b'\xb0\x8a"\xb7\xc9\x01\x00\x000\x80og' b'p%=\xb7\xc9\x01\x00\x00P\x80og']
```

What can cause another problem?

Comment: It's not quite clear from your question. You'd like the bytes of each row of the array, concatenated? Or each column concatenated?

Comment: Or is it that you just want the bytes from a single row?

Comment: you need to iterate each row.
But since you need to calculate has for the row, which is not dependent on any other row, you can use multiprocess. That can speed up to n times where n is the no of cores you have.

Comment: you can use https://github.com/gklc811/duplicate_video_finder/blob/master/duplicateVideoFinder.py at line 68 for an idea to use multiprocessing

Comment: If I have array(100,10) I would like to have array(100,1). In the column I would like to have the whole row as bytes/hex/string... In C++ I could check where the row is in memory, and get all bytes ot each row.

Comment: each row is a type of pandas.Series, so we can get number of bytes needed for the row:  
    b = row.nbytes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to loop. Since you want the bytes from each row, and arrays are row-major, the bytes as they are laid out in memory are exactly the bytes you want in each element of your array, just chunked differently. This is by definition reshaping of the resulting array. You can do:

```
>>> x = np.arange(1000 * 2).reshape(100, 2)
>>> dtype = np.dtype('S{:d}'.format(x.shape[1] * x.dtype.itemsize))
>>> y = np.frombuffer(x.tobytes(), dtype=dtype)
>>> print(y[:5])
[b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01'
b'\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03'
b'\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05'
b'\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07'
b'\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\t']
```

This reinterprets the entire underlying buffer as bytestrings. Each such bytestring (the `dtype`) has length equal to the number of bytes in each row.

There are many other loop-based ways to do this, but one would be using `np.fromiter`. My first solution is several orders of magnitude faster than this, however, as seen by using `IPython`'s `timeit` magic function:

```
In [32]: %timeit np.frombuffer(x.tobytes(), dtype='S16')
2.8 µs ± 318 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [33]: %timeit np.fromiter((row.tobytes() for row in x), dtype='S16')
614 µs ± 18.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: I tried to test code on very simple array and got different results. Please see code above (I added to main question)

Comment: I do not observe the behavior of different results on multiple calls to your function `compute`. For me, doing `len(set(b''.join(compute(x)) for _ in range(100)))` returns 1. Can you verify that you're not calling `compute` on a changing object somehow?

Comment: in jupyter I have good results - only one, the same. When I compile program in command line, I have different results.  I put the code to a file test.py and run: $ python test.py. In script I only one time invoke compute() method. Next I run the code several times.

Comment: That sounds like a difference between your command-line and Jupyter environments. Make sure they're running exactly the same version of Python, NumPy, Pandas, etc.

Comment: It's the same - I have separate environment which I activate before start jupyter kernel. In the same env. I also run script. Current version: 3.6.8 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Dec 30 2018, 18:50:55) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]

Comment: When I run code in interactive mode, the result is the same, so maybe there is a problem durring compilation of code? In interactive mode and in jupyter, function is compiled once, so generate the same result each time with the same values.

Comment: I activated also base env with python 3.7.1 - the effect is the same

Comment: When I changed last command in function, to: y = np.frombuffer(x.tobytes()) I have alwyays the same values:
[8.88799511e-312 8.57382036e-315 8.57382067e-315]  
[8.88798712e-312 8.57382052e-315 8.88807394e-312]  , so there is problem with format function or print?

Comment: The problem is somwhere in conversion from pandas to numpy. When I created numpy array, all seems to work perfectly. I changed x = df.values to x = np.array( ( ["1",1,3], ["2",2,555] ) ).

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for problem with conversion to bytes.

The problem is in automatic conversion column types to type of object, when we have column with strings. Instead of using df.values, we can use a method .to_numpy() and explicitly specify column types, for example:

```
dtype = ([('col1', '|S1'), ('col2', 'i4'), ('col3','i4')] )
x = df.to_numpy(dtype = dtype)
```

Now it works perfectly.

Thanks **bnaecker** for Your solution.