# 'bytes' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a code piece which reads from socket and appends all bytes to an array (this is how it supposed to be work) but when I execute the code below:

```
def receiveData:
     bytemessage = bytearray()
     while True:             
           b = s.recv(1)
           logger.info(str(b))    
           bytemessage.append(b)
```

I am getting this error at the line where 'bytemessage.append(b)'

> 'bytes' object cannot be interpreted as an integer Example

I can log all the bytes I read from socket and all of them is in byte format like this `b'\x01'`
Does anyone have a solution proposal ?

Comment: It will be duplicated with this article. [Python bytes concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28130722/9014308)

Comment: As an aside, you need to check whether you really received 1 byte. Socket.recv returns 0 bytes when the connection is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-bytearray)

> The bytearray class is a mutable sequence of integers in the range 0 <= x < 256.

It's not meant to be container of generic byte objects.

You can add all the parts to a regular list and then join them all together instead

```
def receiveData():
    parts = []
    while True:             
        b = s.recv(1)
        logger.info(str(b))    
        parts.append(b)
    return b''.join(parts)
```

Answer (score 4):

From the docs, [`bytearray`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-bytearray) *is a mutable sequence of integers in the range 0 <= x < 256.* You can only append an integer in that range. A `bytes` object is an immutable array of integers in the same range. So you can do

```
bytemessage.append(b[0])
```

But you can also extend `bytearray`, which is convenient if you have a `bytes` object with more than one byte. This also works

```
bytemessage.extend(b)
```

This will be more space efficient than creating a list of byte objects and combining them at the end. Personally, I would extend even if adding only a single byte as I think the syntax is less cluttered.